# page.CheckOut() throws SPException: URL is invalid even though page exists

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm writing an event receiver for a SharePoint site, and I want this receiver to edit the contents of a basic page after it is created. Here is the function that is giving me issues:

```
public void FillPage(SPSite site, SPItemEventProperties properties, string pageName)
{
    using (site)
    {
        // Wait until the page has been generated
        while (!PageExists(properties.BeforeUrl))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(30000);     // Added so I can check that the URL exists in my browser

        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        SPFile page = web.GetFile(properties.BeforeUrl);
        page.CheckOut();         // Throws SPException: 'URL is invalid'.

        ...
    }
}
```

The PageExists function simply uses an HttpWebRequest pointed to the page that was just generated:

```
public bool PageExists(string url_ending)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri((the root site URL) + url_ending));
    request.Timeout = 15000;
    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        return true;
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        if (we.Message.Contains("Unauthorized"))
        {
            return true; // If it's an authorization error, the page exists but access was denied
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The CheckOut function returns: "SPException: The URL '...' is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web." In addition, I added a breakpoint at the line containing 'page.Checkout()' and examined that page variable, and found that all of its members throw a 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' or a 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException', even though it's pointed to the correct URL. I've also checked that the HttpWebRequest is pointed to the correct URL, which it is, and as mentioned in the comments I check to see that the page exists in my browser before the code can attempt to check it out.

From what searching I did, I found out that this error is often thrown when the database logs are filling up. But from what I found, in that case this error would also occur when attempting to check out documents from the SharePoint site itself, and I have not had that issue; I only get this error when I attempt to check out a page from the event receiver. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Just in case, what is the event you are overriding ?  ItemAdded ?

Comment: The fact you're using `BeforeUrl` let's me assume you're using the `ItemAdding` event instead of `ItemAdded`. So you're catching the event during the page creation process and not after it has been created. So the URL exists, but it's not in your pages library yet. Did you try to evaluate `page.Exists` ? It's probably false. Consider using the `ItemAdded` event instead.

Comment: @Sylvain: I'm using ItemAdded. That said, in regards to LInsoDeTeh's comment, my main reason for using BeforeUrl rather than AfterUrl is because AfterUrl keeps returning null, even when I've confirmed in the browser that the page exists. page.Exists is returning false as well, but that makes no sense because it returns false while I'm looking at the page in the browser, so it clearly does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-spwebgetfilestring/

which explains that **GetFile** can have unexpected results.

There is a workaround provided:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://moss"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
        object o = web.GetFileOrFolderObject("/site/subsite1/Pages/default.aspx");
        if (o is SPFile)
        {
            SPFile f = (SPFile)o;
        }
    }
}
```

you should give it a try !

Comment: Thank you! I gave that code a try and it ended up giving me some of the same problems I had been having, but on that blog there were also examples of how GetFile behaved, and using one of those worked just fine.